# Why is $H^0(X_n, \mathcal{O}_{X_n})$ a local artin ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, schemes, sheaf-cohomology, affine-schemes

Let $V$ be regular, proper and of dimension 2 over $S = $ spec $R$, for $R$ a complete discrete valuation ring with uniformizer $t$, maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and algebraically closed residue field $k$, and let $X$ denote its closed fiber, which we assume to be connected. Let $X_N = V\times_S $ spec $(R/t^{N+1}R)$. I want to show that $H^0(X_{N}, \mathcal{O}_{X_{N}}^*)$ is the group of units in a local Artin ring with residue field $k$.

My initial attempt went as follows:

My goal seems to be to show that $\mathcal{O}_{X_N}(X_N)$ is a local Artin ring with residue field $k$. To this end, I was thinking that by some sort of Künneth formula we should have$$\mathcal{O}_{X_N}(X_N) = H^0(X_N, \mathcal{O}_{X_N})\cong H^0(V,\mathcal{O}_V)\otimes_{R} H^0\left(\text{spec }(R/\mathfrak{m}^{N+1}), \mathcal{O}_{\text{spec} (R/\mathfrak{m}^{N+1})}\right)$$$$= H^0(V,\mathcal{O}_V)\otimes_{R} (R/t^{N+1}R)\cong \mathcal{O}_V(V)/t^{N+1}\mathcal{O}_V(V)$$
and then writing $A = \mathcal{O}_V(V)$ and $B = A/t^NA$, we want to show that $B$ is a local Artin ring with residue field $k$. We see that $A/tA\cong \mathcal{O}_{X}(X) \cong k$ (this gives local and residue field $k$). To see that $B$ is an Artin ring, we note that it's Noetherian since it has a principal maximal ideal $tB$ which is nilpotent, and then it's also Artinian since it's of dimension $0$.

Comment: I'll have to trust your computations because I haven't the slightest clue about them, but I do have feedback on the rest.

To me it is not clear to say "it's Noetherian since it has a principal maximal ideal which is nilpotent."  At least, I don't know what you're basing that on. Possibly you have a lemma I don't know about.

The standard result that comes to mind is Cohen's theorem that says that if the prime ideals are finitely generated, then it is Noetherian. If you already knew it was $0$ dimensional, then your last statement would apply with this and things would be clear.

Comment: I think it would be slightly better if you said "because its maximal ideal is nilpotent, it is $0$ dimensional.  Since additionally its only prime ideal is principal, it is Noetherian by Cohen's theorem. Finally by the theorem about zero dimensional Noetherian rings, it is Artinian.

Comment: I think Kunneth is wrong in this case, there may be a flatness issue (or just the usual “cohomology and base change” issue). Note that $O(X_N)$ has the same reduction as $O(X)$ (which is a finite $k$-algebra) and thus these algebras have the same topological spectrum. In particular, $O(X_n)$ is local iff $X$ is connected, iff (it’s a general theorem but there may be a short argument in your case) $V$ is – which you haven’t assumed.

Comment: @Mindlack Right, sorry, I meant to assume that $X$ is connected.

Comment: @Mindlack Would you mind elaborating on how we get that $\mathcal{O}_{X_n}(X_n)$ is local from $X$ being connected?

Comment: Then $X_N$ is connected, and proper flat over the Artin local ring $R_N=R/(t^{N+1})$ so its ring of global sections is connected and finite over $R_N$, thus is local Artin. But there is still the issue of the residue field, of course…

Comment: @BelowAverageIntelligence : unless I’m mistaken, a finite connected algebra over an Artin Noetherian ring is local, no? Because you can quotient out by the nilpotents of the base, you get a connected finite algebra over a field which must thus be local.

Comment: Sounds right to me. Doesn't that tell us that the residue field of our closed point is an extension of $k$ (and hence equal to $k$)?

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that $k$ was algebraically closed. That settles the matter without even using “cohomology and base change”-style results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135711/discussion-between-belowaverageintelligence-and-mindlack).